# Is there a shortcut to clearing healed or revived Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I am a potion or revive screen to heal/revive Pokemon, is there a shortcut to clear pokemon that are done healing or reviving?

I suspect that there is because I seem to sometimes manage to do it but not quite sure what it is that I did. Of course closing the screen and going back (selecting potion or revive) achieves this, but this is not what I mean.

Is there a shortcut to clear the pokemon list in review/heal without going out?

I am very nearsighted and can't often easily see state of Pokemon healed or revived.

Answer (score 3):

You can tap on several Pokemon at once to restore all of them in the same instant.

If you do this and happen to hit a Pokemon who is already at full health, I've found that the screen refreshes as the restoration animation plays for the ones who are actually being healed; this removes the ones at full health from the list.

Comment: Silph Road posted a [pointer](https://thesilphroad.com/tips-and-news/apply-multiple-potions) describing this time saver.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, there is no way to clear it besides backing out of the screen that I know of.

However, since you are near-sighted, try playing with the sound on (assuming you are able to), as there are audible indicators for whether or not your item use was successful. If you try to heal a Pokemon that is already conscious (revive) or at full health (potion), it will make a standard "error" sound, as opposed to the standard "healing" sound it plays for when a revive or potion is successfully used.

Comment: I find tapping the standard 20-HP healing potion for 10, 11 times very troublesome, due to it not reacting very fast. (11 times, say, if there is a Lapras that almost die but still has a few HP, and you need to charge it up back to 240). So I end up just using the 50 and 200 healing potion and then throw away those 20 HP potion